# How to show filtered result dynamically in table?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filter, angular-material

I'm using 3 inputs to filter my data with a http request with searchvaluechanges and observable.
My problem is to filter the table with the data I get. The table is filled with a http GET when the dashboard is loaded.
Currently I'm not sure if mat-table is the best approach.
I can't see a way to make it work.

Dashboard.component.html

```html
<div class="row align-items-end">
 <div class="col">
  <input (change)="searchValueChange()" [(ngModel)]="filter.articleNumber" id="search-box" matInput
             placeholder="Articlenumber...">
  <input (change)="searchValueChange()" [(ngModel)]="filter.name" matInput placeholder="Name...">
  <input (change)="searchValueChange()" [(ngModel)]="filter.description" matInput placeholder="Description...">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="articles" class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <!-- ArticleNumber Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="articleNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Articlenumber</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article"> {{article.articleNumber}} </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
   </mat-table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Dashboard.component.ts

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public search$: Observable<ArticleSmall[]>;
  public filter: ArticleFilter = {
    articleNumber: '',
    name: '',
    description: ''
  };
  public articles: ArticleSmall[] = [];
  public searchTerms: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.articles);
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['articleNumber', 'name', 'description', 'actions'];

  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getArticles();

    this.search$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(() => this.articleService.search(this.filter.articleNumber, this.filter.name, this.filter.description)));
  }

  public searchValueChange(): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(JSON.stringify(this.filter));
  }
  //this loads all articles with reduced information in the Dashboards Mat-Table
  public getArticles(): void {
    this.articleService.getAllArticles()
      .pipe(
        map((articles: Article[]) => articles.map((article: Article) => {
            const newArticle: ArticleSmall = {
              name: article.name,
              articleNumber: article.articleNumber,
              description: article.description
            };

            return newArticle;
          }
        ))
      ).subscribe((data: ArticleSmall[]) => this.articles = data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to make a few changes :

1. Bind your data table to `MatTableDataSource`

```
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <!-- ArticleNumber Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="articleNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Articlenumber</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article"> {{article.articleNumber}} </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
   </mat-table>
```

1. Subscribe the `$search` to update  `MatTableDataSource`'s data.

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
    // previous code
   this.$search.subscribe(data=>{ // I assumed that your service returns the data not response itself.
    this.dataSource.data = data;
   });
  }
```

**Edit**
3. Also you need to change your initial load of data as below :

```
public getArticles(): void {
    this.articleService.getAllArticles()
      .pipe(
        map((articles: Article[]) => articles.map((article: Article) => {
            const newArticle: ArticleSmall = {
              name: article.name,
              articleNumber: article.articleNumber,
              description: article.description
            };

            return newArticle;
          }
        ))
      ).subscribe((data: ArticleSmall[]) => this.dataSource.data = data);
  }
```

Comment: If I bind it to `MatTableDataSource` I won't have any data in my table, because it does not include the requested data.  After I search in any input field, the data shows, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges()` function when you get the data inside your subscribe method.

You need to inject `ChangeDetectorRefs` in the constructor.

You can find more info [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)